# How to make N-1 inserts/update with mongoose synchronous?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My case is, i have N addresses and N contact information for my user, which are store in a different collection.

Should i store this in the same collection? If not, how can i make the piece of code below work?

Take in mind that the Mongoose queries are Asyn, so, the user could be saved without even the first address being pushed into his model.

```
createUser: function(req, res) {
        var _user = new Models.User(req.body);

        for (var item in _postData.address) {
            var _address = new Models.Address(_postData.address[item]);
            _address.save(function(err) {
                if (err) { res.send({status: 500, message: 'Error while saving address'}); return; }
                _user.address.push(_address);
            });
        }

        for (var item in _postData.contacts) {
            var _contact = new Models.Contact(_postData.contacts[item]);
            _contact.save(function(err) {
                if (err) { res.send({status: 500, message: 'Error while saving contact'}); return; }
                _user.contacts.push(_contact);              
            });
        }

        _user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) { res.send({status: 500, message: 'Error while saving user'}) return; };
            res.send(_user);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where your `_postData` is coming from, but you probably want to source from the `req` or pass it in explicitly.

Bottom line here is that you "both" need to respect the callbacks here as well as realize you can only use the `res` **once**. So a fail anywhere should actually halt the process.

The [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) method from the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library gives you be the best control here, along with [`async.waterfall`](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) for more flow control. Using [`Model.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) also allows you to create all objects in one request, rather than looping with `.save()`:

```js
createUser: function(req,res) {
  async.waterfall(
    [
      // Ouput from here "waterfalls" into the next function
      function(callback) {  
        // This creates one output object with two keys
        // of "array" data for the created items
        async.parallel(
          {
            "address": function(callback) {
                Models.Address.create(_postData.address,callback);
            },
            "contact": function(callback) {
               Models.Contact.create(_postData.contact,callback);
            }
          },
          callback
        );
      },
      // Takes combined output to produce a user
      function(data,callback) {
          var _user = new Model.User(req.body);
          _user.address = data.address;
          _user.contact = data.contact;
          _user.save(callback);
      }
    ],
    function(err,user) {
      // Any errors came directly here, as does all success
      if (err) {
         res.send(500,err);
      } else {
         res.send(user);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Personally though I see further problems here since you are just "blind creating" data for the references. You would get better utility from [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to either "find or create" possible existing data and return that object ( which possibly exists ) to keep in the array as a reference.

But you might also be adjusting to the concepts of working with an object store as opposed to a relational database. In which case, if this data is not actually used by anything other than the current `User`, then you are probably better of "embedding" the data instead of referencing to other collections.

With "embedded" data, it's just one update anyway, since all the data for the other objects is also stored in the same document as the `User` itself.

Food for thought, since you don't seem to be fully "up" on the concepts here.